# How to prevent duplicate global hotkeys in java?

Tags: java, global-hotkey

How to prevent to register duplicate global hotkeys means that do not register already registered hotkeys like CTRL+C or CTRL+V etc.

Comment: Are we talking about Swing/AWT?

Comment: No i am talking about Global hotkey which performs even when apllication not in focus. Like if my application is in tray so i am able to activate by pressing some keys. but need to prevent duplicate hotkeys like if window having CTRL+C predefined so want that list by writing some code in java or using some API.